# Some fields data gets erased when updating a user profile

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In my webapp, users can update their profile.

But in some fields on the update profile page, if the user does not add any info to them, after saving, those fields are deleted, as if they are updated with no data.

But the others are fine.

This is my update pug file:

```
form(action="/account" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data")
  label(for="name") Name
  input(type="text" name="name" value=user.name)
  label(for="email") Email Address
  input(type="email" name="email" value=user.email)
  //- Image Upload
  label(for="photo") Photo
    input(type="file" name="photo" id="photo" accept="image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg")
    if user.photo
      img(src=`/uploads/${user.photo}`, alt=user.name width=200)
  label(for="neighborhood") Neighborhood
  input(type="text" id="neighborhoodUpdate" name="location[vicinity]" value=(user.location && user.location.vicinity))
```

the failing fields are the photo one, and the vicinity(neighborhood) one.

Then i have this route:

```
router.post('/account',
  userController.upload,
  catchErrors(userController.resize),
  catchErrors(userController.updateAccount)
);
```

And in my controller i have this methods:

```
    const multerOptions = {
      storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
      fileFilter(req, file, next) {
        const isPhoto = file.mimetype.startsWith('image/');
        if (isPhoto) {
          next(null, true);
        } else {
          next({ message: 'That filetype isn\'t allowed!' }, false);
        }
      }
    };


    // To upload photos
    exports.upload = multer(multerOptions).single('photo');


    exports.resize = async (req, res, next) => {
  // check if there is no new file to resize
  if (!req.file) {
    next(); // skip to the next middleware
    return;
  }
  const extension = req.file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
  req.body.photo = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`;
  // now we resize
  const photo = await jimp.read(req.file.buffer);
  await photo.resize(800, jimp.AUTO);
  await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${req.body.photo}`);
  // once we have written the photo to our filesystem, keep going!
  next();
};
```

And finally update account:

```
exports.updateAccount = async (req, res) => {
  req.body.location.type = 'Point';

  const updates = {
    name: req.body.name,
    photo: req.body.photo,
    email: req.body.email,
    musicLink: req.body.musicLink,
    genres: req.body.genres,
    location: {
      vicinity: req.body.vicinity,
      address: req.body.location.address,
      type: req.body.location.type,
      coordinates: [
        req.body.location.coordinates[0],
        req.body.location.coordinates[1],
      ]
    }
  };

  const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    { $set: updates },
    { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' }
  );
  req.flash('success', 'Updated the profile!');
  res.redirect('back');
};
```

From what i see, photo and vicinity should not be updated with no data, but somehow if a user does not add new data the old one gets erased.

Any ideas?

Oh, here is my user model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid Email Address'],
    required: 'Please Supply an email address'
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please supply a name',
    trim: true
  },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date,
  props: [
    { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  ],
  // New stuff
  slug: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  genres: [String],
  musicLink: String,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: [{
      type: Number,
      required: 'You must supply coordinates!'
    }],
    address: {
      type: String,
      required: 'You must supply an address!'
    },
    vicinity: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  photo: String,
});
```

Comment: What happens if the user updates photo or vicinity. Is it setting the property correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if the fields are underfined, you probably need to explicitly delete them from the update object, or those fields will be set to undefined. The mere existence of a key in the update object implies a change to that key in the target record when using thr $set operator.

So do something like:

if(!updates.photo) delete updates.photo

Comment: but why dont i have to do that for name or email? those fileds dont get erased.

Comment: try console logging the updates object ala `console.log(JSON.stringify(updates,  null, 2))`

Comment: i get all other fields, but not photo or vicinity field... thats weird.. i would think they should be there.. but i cant spot the error.. they are set up same way as the others......

Comment: You should learn how to run the Express.js locally using VS Code (or similar) to step through your code in a debugger session... that's your best bet to figure out where things go off the rails without having to spot the error statically

Comment: it worked, i think the reason the other fields do not get erased is because that field has to do with multer. thanks!